# Azure Cloud Service "The remote server returned an error: (413) Request Entity Too Large."

Tags: c#, wcf, azure

I have an Azure Cloud Service which hosts a very simple WCF service.

The service has one method which accepts a string of HTML input, it renders the HTML into PDF format and returns the resulting PDF as a byte[].

I call this service from an Azure web site and it works fine for a small to moderate amount of HTML, but when the HTML gets a bit longer, I'm getting the following error returned from the server:

```
The remote server returned an error: (413) Request Entity Too Large.
```

My configuration on the Azure WCF service is as follows:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="LargeSettings" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" sendTimeout="00:05:00" receiveTimeout="00:05:00">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="20000000" maxStringContentLength="12000" maxArrayLength="21504000" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service name="PDFSrvcRole.PDFSrvc">
    <endpoint bindingConfiguration="LargeSettings" name="PDFSrvcRole.PDFSrvc" address="http://xxxxx.cloudapp.net/PDFSrvc.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="PDFSrvcRole.IPDFSrvc" />
  </service>
</services>
```

Answer (score 0):

Grrrrrrr!

Well it's now all sorted, so a few learnings.

First of all, yes Azure WCF services do work, but they are a niggling pain to configure.
But this is more a criticism of WCF in general, not Azure.

I had to do a few things to get this working...

I created a fresh Windows Desktop application which made it easier for me to debug the target service and get the configuration working.

I also needed to turn customErrors mode=”Off” on the WCF service so I could see what was going on.

Then I had issues with 
BUT I learnt that it seems to be important to keep this key and keep it set to true. If you don't have this key, then add it.

Then it was asking for a relative address (or blank) because I had the above key enabled, so I set address="" because relative values such as "Service.svc" didn't work and added additional complexities which were a pain.

Then it was critical that I added transferMode="streamed" to the client that was calling the service. This worked for both Windows Applications as well as Web Sites hosted on Azure. ANYTHING that calls this service, needs that setting set to streamed.

Enabling that, caused another error to appear which told me that my value of 12000 for maxStringContentLength wasn't long enough. I then increased that to about 5 hundred billion.

Then it worked!!! Perfectly, no more errors and I can now upload any sized request.

Now I need to reduce those numbers a bit to reduce risk of DOS attacks etc.

It's been a saga, but the end result definitely works nicely now that it's all setup.