# Azure Cloud Service "The remote server returned an error: (413) Request Entity Too Large - Net Framework 4.8

Tags: wcf

I have a Wcf service that when is used in local whith visual studio works perfectly but when i deploy it on Azure it returns the following error message.
**System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException: The remote server returned an unexpected response: (413) Request Entity Too Large.**
at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)

Here is the web.config settings. where am I going wrong.
<system.serviceModel>

```
 <bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
   <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
    <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" />
   </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
  <wsHttpBinding>
     <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" />
            </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior>
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
                <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483646" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="4294967295" />
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
<system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true" indentsize="0">
        <listeners>
            <add name="myAppInsightsListener" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TraceListener.ApplicationInsightsTraceListener, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TraceListener" />
        </listeners>
    </trace>
</system.diagnostics>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try using the following binding configuration to solve the problem:

```
<bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2000000" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Besides, this case shows another way to solve the exception. [Azure Cloud Service "The remote server returned an error: (413) Request Entity Too Large."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25235908/azure-cloud-service-the-remote-server-returned-an-error-413-request-entity-t)

Hope it helps.